# V-for remove element

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, v-for

I'm working on a Vue/Quasar app and what I want to do is show the following layout only once when the page is loaded:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(section, index) in sections" :key="index">
    <div class="row q-gutter-md">
      <q-input v-model="sectionName" bottom-slots dense :label="labelText">
        <template v-slot:append>
          <q-btn flat dense icon="add" color="grey " @click="addNew" />
          <q-btn flat dense icon="delete" color="grey " @click="removeSection" />
        </template>
      </q-input>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the code snippet from the script section:

```
    setup() {
    const sections = ref(1);
    const addNew = () => {
      sections.value++
    };
    const removeSection = () => {
     //...
    };
    return{
     //...}
```

The `addNew` function works well: new sections will be added to the screen. But how could I remove a particular (which was clicked) section? What should I change?

Comment: you should define sections as an array rather than number like ``const sections = ref([]);`` and then simply define your remove/add functions to mutate ``sections`` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a parameter to your removeSection function (ex: index) after that once you clicked on delete button you will know which index should be deleted. You will be able to find the item in your sections that you wanted to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can define sections like array of objects with id and value:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const sections = ref([{id: new Date(), sectionName: ''}]);
    const addNew = (i) => {
      sections.value = [...sections.value, {id: new Date(), sectionName: ''}]
    };
    const removeSection = (i) => {
      sections.value.length > 1 && sections.value.splice(sections.value[i], 1)
    };
    return{ sections, addNew, removeSection }
   }
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.10.1/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="q-app">
  <div v-for="(section, index) in sections" :key="index">
    <div class="row q-gutter-md">
      <q-input v-model="section.sectionName" bottom-slots dense :label="labelText">
        <template v-slot:append>
          <q-btn flat dense icon="add" color="grey " @click.prevent="addNew" />
          <q-btn flat dense icon="delete" color="grey " @click.prevent="removeSection(index)" />
        </template>
      </q-input>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{sections}}
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.10.1/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```